# After creating a Custom CellView of a tableView, still i am not getting the multiple column view. Can anyone help me out?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I am having an app wherein i have created the custom cell that is UITableViewCell. In the main view i need the 4 rows with 4 columns. But i am not getting the column view, just the rows as seen in the screenshot.
[image]

I went through many related post but did not understand them clearly. Can someone give me exact explanations and the related code?

Comment: Could you provide some more information? Like, what is your data model that should be displayed in the table and what have you tried to add to the cells in storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: I have warehouse details to be given in one of the column and location in another,stock details in the third and availability in the fourth. I created a UITableViewCell which gives the custom cell then imported the file to the UITableView and in the main view just initialised the tableView. Still i just get the rows and not the columns.

Comment: Okay, could you show me the content of the method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in your `UITableViewController` subclass?

Comment: int iRowIndex =   indexPath.row;static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";NSString *strCellType = @"Data";if(iRowIndex == 0)
strCellType = @"Header";PartCellView *cell = (PartCellView*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil){cell = [[PartCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}

Comment: else{[cell cleanCell];[cell addContentViews];
if(cell.lblWareHouse){cell.lblWareHouse.text = nil;}
if(cell.lblLocation){cell.lblLocation.text = nil;}
if(cell.lblInStockQuantity){cell.lblInStockQuantity.text = nil;}
    if(iRowIndex == 0)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; 
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

Comment: Thats what i have in the method of cellForRowAtIndex

Comment: Alright, we're getting closer. ;) So far I cannot see, where you are putting content into your cell's labels. What happens in `[cell cleanCell];` and `[cell addContentViews];`?

Comment: I have set all to nil in cleanCell. self.lblWareHouse  = nil;
    self.lblLocation  = nil;
    self.lblInStockQuantity  = nil;
    self.lblAvailableQuantity = nil;
In addContentViews i haven't added anything since i am confused what to do there.

Comment: I know i got to add labels to get the data in the tableView but will that give me partitions so that columns are created?

Comment: I recommend you to read [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html). What you want to do can definitely be done using a UITableView by adding 4 labels to the cell. Just go through the apple doc to see, how Storyboard, prototype cells and code glue together.

Comment: oh ok. Thanx for the help. I will check out the apple doc.

Comment: Hey that apple doc did not help me. Its not giving a way to partition the tableview to get the columns. :(

Comment: Please see my answer, that I have just posted below. If this is in some way what you are visually expecting, then this could be a starting point for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got the question and some of the comments right, a table with four columns is required. My approach to realize such a view would be the following.

- Add a UITableViewController in the storyboard.
- Choose Dynamic Prototypes cells (and optionally set the number of cells to 2, if you
  like to add a header row later on).
- Select the cell and set the Style to Custom.
- Set the cell's identifier to "WarehouseCell".
- Set the header cell's identifier to "HeaderCell".
- Add four UILabels to each cell and arrange them as required.
- Give the UILabels of the "WarehouseCell" the tags 1 to 4.

Assuming you have a data model that consists of an array of dictionaries to store your warehouses (e.g. `@property NSArray *warehouses;`), you could implement something like this in your UITableViewController subclass...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.warehouses = @[
                        @{@"warehouse":@"1",@"location":@"North Pole",@"stock":@"1.200",@"available":@"YES"},
                        @{@"warehouse":@"2",@"location":@"South Pole",@"stock":@"0",@"available":@"NO"},
                        @{@"warehouse":@"7",@"location":@"Moon Base",@"stock":@"8.500",@"available":@"YES"},
                        @{@"warehouse":@"10",@"location":@"Mars",@"stock":@"n/a",@"available":@"n/a"}
                       ];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.warehouses.count + 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WarehouseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        ((UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1]).text = [self.warehouses[indexPath.row-1] valueForKey:@"warehouse"];
        ((UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2]).text = [self.warehouses[indexPath.row-1] valueForKey:@"location"];
        ((UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3]).text = [self.warehouses[indexPath.row-1] valueForKey:@"stock"];
        ((UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:4]).text = [self.warehouses[indexPath.row-1] valueForKey:@"available"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The resulting view should look like this, which make a iOS7-esque looking table.

[image: Table example running in simulator]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a `UITableView` for creating columns. Try using an `UICollectionView` instead.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use UICollectionView:

Comment: I need to get 4 rows and 4 colums with some data in each cell. Can you please tell me how to go about?

Comment: Check out these tutorials: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/
and
http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: Depending on the data that should be displayed, the UICollectionView is not suitable. A simple table with four columns could be realized by simply adding four UILabels to the table cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS6.0 or later then UICollectionView is perhaps the best option otherwise you can use any of the following libraries:

1. KKGridView
2. UIGridView
3. AQGridView
4. NRGridView
5. MMGridView
6. WCGridView

Comment: UICollectionView will only give me cells with images right? I need to have some data in each cell. How will i get that?